# How do I make an html file include itself without refreshing the page each time a button or link is clicked?

Tags: php, html

Beginner's question here :

file #1 : file1.html (one dataset)

```
//header, body and some other stuff
<form action="some_logic.php">
    <input type="text" name="data1" placeholder="data1">
    <input type="text" name="data2" placeholder="data2">
    <input type="submit" value="Ok!">       
</form>
//end of the html
```

file #2 : (I don't even know what this file should be : php? html? js?)

```
//usual stuff
    include 'file1.html';     //OR
    <!--#include file="file1.html"-->
    #logic to replicate file1.html with a button
```

I need to have the file1's code repeated once each time the user clicks on a button (or a link or whatever) and I would like this to work without refreshing the page (or at least without questionning the server over and over and without deleting the current datas). The server uses php7.

I need this because I do not know in advance how much datasets the user will create.
It would be awesome if this could be done with javascript! (since I doubt this can be achieved with php/html only) Although I have never used js until now.

Comment: make all the files .php files (even the ones which contain nothing but HTML) and you can use `require()` or `include()` in PHP to include other files in the final output.

Comment: However if you're asking how to submit data repeatedly without refreshing the page then you're going to want to use JavaScript to send an AJAX to submit the form (instead of posting the form back in the usual way). That way you don't need to keep repeatedly loading file1.html at all (or including it in any other pages) - it simply never goes away from the browser in the first place, and the user can submit data as many times as you let them. You could of course also use JavaScript to add what they just submitted into the page as they go along, so they can see what they're doing

Comment: I suggest you maybe do a bit more research / do some tutorials or something so you can get the basic concepts of web pages and applications, and how HTTP works, straight in your head before you continue.

Comment: All you need is jQuery/JavaScript for this, if you want dynamic content then use PHP and AJAX too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch data from server without refreshing the webpage using JavaScript Ajax. Here you can create an event listener to send a request to the server. The data can be plain text, html, json,  xml or whatever you want. Just create Ajax request for events. Then update the webpage using the response data.